# What is the right response for null nested property of resource

Tags: api, rest, restful-architecture, http-response-codes

Consider these endpoints on an API that returns exclusively Json:

- `GET /cities/{id}/stores`
- `GET /cities/{id}/mayor`

Both `store` and `mayor` are objects that can have scalar properties of their own.

The `city->stores` relationship is one-to-many, but the `city->mayor` relationship is one-to-one. In both cases the result can be null.

I would agree that

`GET /stores/{id}`, `GET /cities/{id}` and `GET /mayors/{id}` should return 404 when a resource with that id does not exist.

However, if a city has no stores then I would expect `GET cities/{id}/stores` to return `[]`.

My question is, given that a city has no current mayor, what should 
`GET /cities/{id}/mayor` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If mayor for given city is not set and it exists in one-to-one relation, `404` status code should be returned.

Returning `null` values does not make sense - since API consumers won't know how to cope with this value.

Another option is to change this endpoint from *mayor* to *mayors* and return empty collection or collection with one entry always - however this is not a good idea, should be well documented and in general I regret that I suggested it ;)

You can also embed mayor into city and then in returned JSON set its value to null if not present.

Comment: Embedding mayor into city is always an option, but really I was asking this question because I'd like to get away from embedding too many nested entities in a response, it means more db calls on the server side and serialization is sometimes costly. Plus authorization checks become hell if you start nesting resources in responses - you never know what's viewable where. Still, 404 seems to be the most logical response - just seems a bit strange that client would get an error just for checking is a property of the resource null or not. Thanks!

Comment: In such case maybe you should investigate a resource query language?